# How to determine size of data (allocated and deallocated) during runtime

Tags: c++

I have two questions:

1.) I want to do memory profiling of my code in a function-wise manner. The code can have any STL containers. Is there a way of doing this in linux?

2.) The second one is due to my naivety!! If I have a data-structure

```
template < class T1 > struct somestruct
{
std::set < T1 > v1;
std::vector < T1 > v2;
std::vector < T1 > v3;
};
```

and I know the sizes of v1, v2 and v3 then can I do a straightforward calculation of the size of the structure based on sizeof(T1) or would I have to take care of padding?

Comment: You can get a feel for the size of a `struct` through looking at the members, but you should use `sizeof` to get a definitive answer. These are 2 pretty different question; they should probably be split.

Comment: sizeof may not be functional when dealing with dynamic objects.

Comment: `sizeof` always work, but it might not do what you want it to do.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain sizeof will give compile-time size info. Run-time size could be different. Correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: You are correct, but the size of a `struct` cannot change. The size of what it represents may change.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain kewl. Many thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [the valgrind *massif* heap profiler](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) on linux:

```
valgrind --tool=massif ./testprogram
```

Then,

```
ms_print ./massif.out.16766 # replace with actual generated name
```

Will give you a chart with samples and peak heap usage, and a breakdown like so

```
19.63^                                               ###                      
     |                                               #                        
     |                                               #  ::                    
     |                                               #  : :::                 
     |                                      :::::::::#  : :  ::               
     |                                      :        #  : :  : ::             
     |                                      :        #  : :  : : :::          
     |                                      :        #  : :  : : :  ::        
     |                            :::::::::::        #  : :  : : :  : :::     
     |                            :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  ::   
     |                        :::::         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : :: 
     |                     @@@:   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |                   ::@  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |                :::: @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |              :::  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |            ::: :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |         :::: : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |       :::  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |    :::: :  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
     |  :::  : :  : : :  : @  :   :         :        #  : :  : : :  : :  : : @
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->KB     0                                                                   29.48

Number of snapshots: 25
 Detailed snapshots: [9, 14 (peak), 24]
```

The breakdowns would be like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10         10,080           10,080           10,000            80            0
 11         12,088           12,088           12,000            88            0
 12         16,096           16,096           16,000            96            0
 13         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0
 14         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0
99.48% (20,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->49.74% (10,000B) 0x804841A: main (example.c:20)
| 
->39.79% (8,000B) 0x80483C2: g (example.c:5)
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x80483E2: f (example.c:11)
| | ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
| |   
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048436: main (example.c:25)
|   
->09.95% (2,000B) 0x80483DA: f (example.c:10)
  ->09.95% (2,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
```

Comment: Thank you for recommending valgrind. The problem with valgrind is that it can be compiled only with gcc :( Are there any other opensource profilers available

Answer (score 0):

Straight `sizeof()` of struct will return compile-time size, i.e. it will not take in consideration actual size of containers. So, you probably want to manually iterate through each container and add up sizes of each element.

But easier way for you is probably to use profiler (e.g. gprof (GNU Profiler)) or any other

Comment: Yes, take a look here http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html . Although, this solution is just a workaround. As far as I know gprof doesn't work correctly with multithreaded applications as is, it profiles main thread. For multithreaded application you probably want to look at OProfile (http://oprofile.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I fail to see how gprof would help with memory profiling. Does it have new features that I'm unaware of?